# Using imported module inside the @Component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I'm trying the set the `templateUrl` based on a module property that I imported it before the @Component , i.e -

```
import { details } from './details';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-cmp',
  templateUrl: details.typeA ? './pageA.html' : './pageB.html'
})
```

When I'm making that I'm getting an error - `Module not found`,
But when I use the imported module within the `ngOnInit()` I have an access to this module.

How can I use the imported module in the `templateUrl` line ?

Comment: try to assign `details` to variable then use that variable in ternary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another solution.

You can achieve this using `ng-template` and then dynamically update the template accordingly your condition like this -

```
import {
  Compiler, Component, Injector, VERSION, ViewChild, NgModule, NgModuleRef,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<ng-container #vc></ng-container>`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc;
  conditionValue = 'myCondition';

  constructor( 
    private _compiler: Compiler,
    private _injector: Injector,
    private _m: NgModuleRef<any>
  ) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    let tmpCmp;
    if (this.conditionValue === 'myCondition') {
      tmpCmp = Component({
        templateUrl: './e.html'})(class {
      });
    } else {
      // something else
    }

    const tmpModule = NgModule({declarations: [tmpCmp]})(class { });

    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
      .then((factories) => {
        const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
        const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
        cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
        this.vc.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
      })
  }
}
```

[#Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dyanmically-template?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

For more info, refer -

- https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e